# Any smart touch tv that supports silverlight through its native web browser?

Tags: web-applications, microsoft, silverlight

I have developed a silverlight application and would like to test it in a touch environment, so my question is are there any smart TV where I can show this application through their native web browser or do I have to connect a computer (with windows 7/8) to a touch monitor (in order to support silverlight)?

The TV monitor should be placed in a corridor and should be around 40 " big. 2 touch points are enough but 6 would not be bad either (but price is of concern here).

Of course it could be a all in one touch computer but these tend to be rather expensive when they have such a big screen (Microsoft table etc)

Sorry if this question is misplaced but didn't find any other forum that would fit this subject, if there is please let me know and I will correct the mistake =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly most Smart TV's that can play many formats and install apps run on Linux, Microsoft have not released Silverlight for Linux and there is lite versions for Linux of [Silverlight called moonlight](http://www.mono-project.com/Moonlight) but in all honesty its very limited and most things simply don't work.

Your best bet is to purchase a Windows Tablet or build yourself a Media Center PC for those screens and test your application that way.